# Axios PUT options ok, but not doing the real call (POST does work)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Am a bit confused about what is happening here. I have done all my CORS research and made it work with my POST and GET request, that is all fine and shining. But now I needed a PUT request (cause put stands for update). And my OPTIONS request is all fine but it is not doing the real call. If i change the methods to POST, in laravel and Axios (in VueJs), it works. Anyone has a clue, here is my response from server:

[image]

Versions:

- Axios - 0.18.0 (latest release)

Any more information required, let me know and I will try my best to provide that.

UPDATE: sorry i made a typo in my last sentence: "If i change the methods to PUT, in laravel and Axios (in VueJs), it works"

Methods should be POST not PUT, so like this: "If i change the methods to POST, in laravel and Axios (in VueJs), it works"

Comment: Do the `PUT` method is allowed for this route in laravel. If you use [Laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) check if the method is allowed too.

Comment: @Core972 isnt the 'Allow: PUT' more then enough to know? and if it wasnt allowed, should the status code not have been 200 but 400?

Comment: That's the response to the `OPTIONS` call which tells the client what's allowed in the CORS request. It will not send a 400 error because it does not yet know what request you intend to do. The browser will just not make the request unless it's a `PUT` request. All CORS security checks are imposed client-side

Comment: Did you create routes for both the options and the put request? I had a similar issue not too long ago

Comment: @mur762 options should not be a route method. Its just a cors thing. I do know that it is possible to create a options route in laravel, but i have not really looked into it. But it works now, see my own answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I had to put a header for allowing the PUT method:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"); <----
```

First I did not had that header, but my GET and POST worked fine, so default header is set for only GET/POST maybe? Now I defined all the methods by myself and now it is working. I know this can be better done in Laravel with a cors package or make an middleware, but I will do that in the future. For now this works.